# $scope conflict when submitting form

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble to debug a code that I've not written and to understand where the problem is coming from (I am not an angular developer).
I have the following : a main controller, which initializes a radio object : it's called when you refresh the window :

```
    $scope.radio_structure = {
        data: {
            localisations: []
        },
        streams: []
    };

    $scope.stream_structure = {
        url: ""
    };


    $scope.localisation_structure = {
        continent: "",
        country: "",
        city: ""
    }
    $scope.radio = angular.copy($scope.radio_structure);
```

And also a function to submit the data of the form.

```
    $scope.submit = function () {
        console.log($scope.radio);
        radioFact.add($scope.radio).then(
            function (success) {
                flashesFact.show(success.data);
                $location.url('/search');
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                var response = {
                    type: 'danger',
                    msg: error.status + ' => ' + error.statusText
                }
                flashesFact.show(response);
            }
        );
    };
```

and in my add controller, I have the following initialization :

```
    // Init stream data structure
    $scope.radio.streams.push(angular.copy($scope.stream_structure));
    // Init localisation data structure
    $scope.radio.data.localisations.push(angular.copy($scope.localisation_structure));
```

And the data is binded with the ng-model :

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="radio.data.name"
           ng-required="true"
           placeholder="{{'RADIO_NAME_PH' | translate}}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback feedback-success"
          ng-show="suggest.name.$valid"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback feedback-error"
          ng-show="suggest.name.$invalid"></span>

    <p ng-show="suggest.name.$error.required && !suggest.name.$pristine" class="help-block">
        {{'RADIO_NAME_MISERR' | translate}}
    </p>
</div>
```

And the submit button triggering the form submit :

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"
        class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3 btn btn-success" ng-disabled="suggest.$invalid"
        ng-click="submit($event)">
    {{'FORM_SUBMIT' | translate}}
</button>
```

And the method called when the submit is triggered :

```
    radio.add = function (data) {
        var path = '*****';
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '*****' + path,
            data: data,
            headers: {
                'path': path
            }
        });
    };
```

The problem is the following : when I submit the form data the first time, it works as expected. However, after submiting the form, I can decide to send a new one, and if I do so, and that I set new values in the form, the values are not reset and I submit the same data with the first submit.

My understanding would be that there is a conflict with the scopes

Comment: Hmm doesn't look like it's the scopes. Where is the element with the `ng-click` event that triggers `$scope.submit`? Also, what is `radioFact`? Where is the code for that?

Comment: I added the missing information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make an init function where you define the starting position:

```
$scope.init = function() {
    $scope.radio_structure = {
        data: {
            localisations: []
        },
        streams: []
    };

    $scope.stream_structure = {
        url: ""
    };


    $scope.localisation_structure = {
        continent: "",
        country: "",
        city: ""
    }
    $scope.initRadio();
}

$scope.initRadio = function() {
    $scope.radio = angular.copy($scope.radio_structure);
}

$scope.init();
```

Then init again after successfull submit:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    console.log($scope.radio);
    radioFact.add($scope.radio).then(
        function (success) {
            flashesFact.show(success.data);
            $scope.initRadio();
            $location.url('/search');
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            var response = {
                type: 'danger',
                msg: error.status + ' => ' + error.statusText
            }
            flashesFact.show(response);
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: This gives me the same result, twice the same data

Comment: You perform an action with ng-click AND you submit the form. The form tag is not added to your code, but I guess it triggers the same function. Probably that causes the double data

Comment: I don't really understand what you said. The ng-click triggers the "add()"method of a service (I added it in the code), and that method gets the radio object from the scope and submits it to a server with a POST request.

Comment: The submit button has `ng-click="submit($event)"` attribute. So, clicking this button will trigger the submit method AND submit the form (`button type="submit"`)

Comment: try to change the button tag to a div and remove the type="submit" attribute.

Comment: It gives me the same result : the problem is not that I trigger twice the upload function, the problem is that, when I make a first form submit, and that I make a second one after (in the same session), I send the same data again

Comment: Where do you initialize `$scope.radio`? I will update my answer with the initialization.

Comment: In my main controller. Sorry if my question is not clear!

Comment: It does... You fixed that, thanks! I tried few things like that yesterday, but I didn't manage to make it work : could you explain me what was I doing bad in my initialization?

Comment: Glad it worked! It is good practice to use an init function for setting all initial values. And this function can be used to reinitialize if necessary. Otherwise it will keep the values set by ng-model. In this case you only need to reinitialize the radio value, so I splitted the init function in two parts. Now you only need to call the initRadio function after submission.